# Android - Back button from FragmentActivity to another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let's say I have a ListFragment A that is rooted from MainActivity A. User presses a list from List A and go to the FragmentActivity B. FragmentActivity holds 3 tabs of fragments.

So, I want to put an up navigation to the FragmentActivity B, so that it goes back to ListFragment A. How do I go about that?

This is my try, so far no luck:

```
public class ItemDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    ...

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                LatestFragment fragment = new LatestFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.pager, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

`LatestFragment` is the ListFragment A I want to go back to.

However, I got an error that says I have to implement `OnLatestSelectedListener` because in LatestFragment, I already put an interface to pass values.

What else can I go inside `onOptionsItemSelected`?

Comment: A and B are different Activities?

Comment: Yes. A is the main activity (holds nav drawer), whereas B is the item details (holds tab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you started ItemDetailActivity with a standard intent, you should just be able to use back  action like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If fragment A is in your main activity then you can also look in to using ActionBar. Back button takes you to the main activity. It is quite easy to implement as well.

Comment: It goes to the wrong Fragment of MainActivity. How do I specify so that it really goes to the previous Fragment of MainActivity? In this case, LatestFragment. Not other fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your FragmentActivityB has got the back button.
if not you can get it by

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
<meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="#######" />
```

Now you can just **identify fragments rooted with MainActivity using some flags like ViewNumber(1,2,3)**.

Implement the method **onMenuItemSelected(....)** and pass the **viewNumber** ie; the Fragment Which you want to show.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
      //We are implementing this method to respond to the back button on the action bar.

      int itemId = item.getItemId();
        switch (itemId) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("viewNumber",2);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }//onMenuItemSelected
```

In **MainActivity** get the **viewNumber** using **Bundles**, and you can have some method like this to work out and display the desired Fragment.

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {

    case 1:
        fragment = new ListFragmentB();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new ListFragmentA();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            }
        }
       }
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for you solution. I think this might be useful to other functions in my app :)

Comment: @AimanB  Another very important area where you can implement it is [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) because every view which display after clicking on DrawerList is actually a Fragment, so it becomes the same requirement what you wanted to do. :)

Comment: Am I able to put both back button and Nav Drawer in one Activity?

Comment: @AimanB No, the position of back button and drawer button are same by default, you can only have one. If you want to have both then in my opinion you have to change the drawer button location or probably have to compensate with the drawer in that particular Activity.

Comment: Oh, umm. I guess I'll just stick to back button :) Thanks for the tips Soni